# How does the nlp object work in spacy library?

Tags: python, oop, nlp, spacy, language-concepts

From what I understand so far, it is an instance of the 'Language' class in spacy, and can process text and perform a bunch of operations on it.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

# Process the text
doc = nlp(
    "In 1990, more than 60% of people in East Asia were in extreme poverty. "
    "Now less than 4% are."
)

print(doc[0])
//prints "In"
```

The question that bothers me is that how does an object accept an argument(a string in this case) like a class does? What is the process?

I tried the following code to check if an object can receive an argument..

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,a=1):
        self.a = a
        
    def printa(self):
        print(self.a)

abc = ABC()
abc(2)
abc.printa()
```

It gives me an error:
`TypeError: 'ABC' object is not callable`

spacy seems to be doing the same thing and it works..How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow an object to be called like a function by providing a `__call__` method:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,a=1):
        self.a = a

    def printa(self):
        print(self.a)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print(self.a, *args)


abc = ABC()
abc(2)
abc.printa()
```

Output:

```
1 2
1
```

Implementing the `__call__` method makes the object callable.

As for the actual type of `nlp`:

```
>>> type(nlp)
<class 'spacy.lang.en.English'>
```

And it does indeed have `__call__`:

```
>>> hasattr(nlp, '__call__')
True
```